# Reduce size of images used in SO blog

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog

While looking at the new article [New Kids on the Block](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/06/12/new-kids-block-understanding-developers-entering-workforce-today/), I've noticed the author avatar was taking some time to load. [Looking at the image](https://stackoverflow.blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/profile2017.jpg), it is indeed quite heavy: 2,6MB for a 3339x3339 pixels image displayed at only 48x48 pixels...

Shouldn't you compress/resize these images?

Comment: Looks like it's probably just that one image, other author images are much smaller.

Comment: Probably, I've used the plural in case there were other cases like this one, didn't checked.

Comment: Applicable: http://idlewords.com/talks/website_obesity.htm

Comment: I'm sure [Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5468471/julia-silge) is delighted that you can zoom in to even the most minute of details on her face!

Comment: The "Stack Overflow" link in **[Julia's page in Stack Overflow Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/authors/juliasilge/)** is invalid - `http://[optional,%20url%20to%20your%20stack%20overflow/exchange%20profile%5D`

Comment: this could kill bandwidth with limited data plan on mobile...

Comment: @Pang Ha! That's awesome.

Comment: @DavidG I wish you could but the image is not even sharp at 100%. This is probably what happens when scanning a photo the size of the stamp at 2400 dpi :-)

Comment: This has been brought up before. Can't find the post but those avatars have been huge for quite some time.

Comment: Somewhat related; I just noticed that some browser vendors are considering automatically blocking images like this which use an unreasonable amount of bandwidth: https://github.com/WICG/interventions/issues/40

Comment: For those wondering: no it's not on the blog repository https://github.com/StackExchange/stack-blog, through Nick fixed it https://github.com/StackExchange/stack-blog/commit/5de0e4c7ae618af0874406c4b5372304da95914b

Comment: Her avatar below the post coming from disqus is quite reasonably sized.

Comment: https://github.com/StackExchange/stack-blog/issues/263

Comment: Working on it... Gotta track down who has the right permissions on the blog to fix it up.

Comment: Also relevant: https://danluu.com/web-bloat/

Comment: Not as big as Julia's avatar but still oversized, on [Download Stack Overflow’s 2017 Developer Survey Data](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/06/15/download-stack-overflows-2017-developer-survey-data/) [Kevin Troy's avatar](https://stackoverflow.blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/8b9oX.jpg) is at 800x800px.

Comment: This appears to have been fixed for Julia now, though yes Kevin's is still an issue. cc: @AdamLear

Comment: @D.G. Thanks for the heads up, I pinged folks internally about that one.

Comment: 800x800 is still excessive, but it's at least an order of magnitude smaller than 3339x3339.

Answer (score -13):

[Nick saves the day](https://github.com/StackExchange/stack-blog/commit/5de0e4c7ae618af0874406c4b5372304da95914b), without causing something worse *phew*, and changes the image to something that isn't so BIGLY. Now we need someone to figure out how long is the html cached or if a rebuild is needed.

Comment: Nick, if you are reading this, we need a rebuild.

Comment: Yes, please, rebuild and publish now!!1!!! This bug report has more them 100 upvotes !!!!11!

Comment: The blog doesn't use Jekyll, or that repository anymore; a rebuild will not help.

Comment: Saves the day? That was done 4 months ago!

Comment: @D.G. how do you know?

Comment: @DavidG well, it was a day... 4 months ago... :D

Comment: @Braiam Because I work with the blog (marketing) team on the podcast, and was consulted on (part of) the last migration. Also, the last commit was back in Feb, yet the blog keeps on updating ;)

Comment: @D.G. darn it, so... what we are using now?

Comment: Pay no attention to the Wordpress behind the curtain!

Comment: @D.G. so the Stack Overflow went from [Wordpress to Jekyll](https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/07/02/how-we-built-our-blog/) and now they're back on Wordpress?

Comment: @g00glen00b Basically. The difference is that now it's externally hosted Wordpress instead of something our SRE team has to maintain.